# skip duplicate values in array in loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement

i have array of serial numbers for books categorized as read and unread books.
when ever there is book that is read i place read in array after that serial number as follow.

```
array(
"1234567890","read",
"2345678901","read",
"2345678901",
"2345678901",
"1234561231",
"3333333333","read",
"3333333333"
)
```

status is unread for all others
My code is given below.

```
$scannedbook=array("0075423658","0012366321","read","0012366321","0012366321","0012366321","0132546874","read","0132546874");
$lenghtofarray = count($scannedbook);
$readbook = "0";
$unreadbook = "0";
for ($x = 0; $x <= $lenghtofarray-1; $x++) {
    if($scannedbook[$x] == 'read'){
        continue ;
    }
    if($scannedbook[$x+1] == 'read'){
        $readbook++;
        for($i=$x; $i<$lenghtofarray-1; $i++){
            if($scannedbook[$x] == $scannedbook[$i+1]){
             $unreadbook++;
            }
        }   
    }
    else{
        $unreadbook++;
    }
echo $scannedbook[$x]." readbook=".$readbook."unreadbook=".$unreadbook."<br />";
        $readbook = "0";
        $unreadbook = "0";
}
```

my output is

```
1234567890: 0 unread, 1 read 
2345678901: 2 unread, 1 read 
2345678901: 1 unread, 0 read 
2345678901: 1 unread, 0 read 
1234561231: 1 unread, 0 read 
3333333333: 1 unread, 1 read 
3333333333: 1 unread, 0 read
```

i just need to skip those with repeated values if they are already checked like 3rd 4rth and 7th in bold values and need result like this

```
    1234567890: 0 unread, 1 read
    2345678901: 2 unread, 1 read
    1234561231: 1 unread, 0 read
    3333333333: 1 unread, 1 read
```

Comment: Use $array=array_unique($array);

Comment: can you please help me where should i place it inside loop .

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you want your code to do? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: i dont need to remove duplicate values.i just want to loop it for first time but if values get repeated in loop , they should be skipped like i added my required output .

Comment: @Anders dear my code is looping through duplicate values. i need to skip out my result witth  3rd 4rth and 7th row

Comment: @Anders 

i have edited my question kindly see if you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php
$scannedbook=array("0075423658","0012366321","read","0012366321","0012366321","0012366321","0132546874","read","0132546874");
$lenghtofarray = count($scannedbook);
$readbook = "0";
$unreadbook = "0";
$dummyArray=array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= $lenghtofarray-1; $x++) {
    if($scannedbook[$x] == 'read'){
        continue ;
    }
    if($scannedbook[$x+1] == 'read'){
        $readbook++;
        for($i=$x; $i<$lenghtofarray-1; $i++){
            if($scannedbook[$x] == $scannedbook[$i+1]){
             $unreadbook++;
            }
        }   
    }
    else{
        $unreadbook++;
    }
    if(!in_array($scannedbook[$x],$dummyArray))
    {
    echo $scannedbook[$x]." readbook=".$readbook."unreadbook=".$unreadbook."<br />";
    array_push($dummyArray,$scannedbook[$x]);
    }
        $readbook = "0";
        $unreadbook = "0";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add before output

```
if (!isset($arr[$readbook][$unreadbook])) {
    $arr[$readbook][$unreadbook] = 1;
} else {
   $readbook = "0";
   $unreadbook = "0";
   continue;
}
```

Comment: StagnantIce Ale
i have edited my question please go through it if you can help me

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the PHP function `array_unique()` to remove duplicate values from an array.
It works like this.

```
$input = array(4, "4", "3", 4, 3, "3");
$result = array_unique($input);
var_dump($result);
```

The output would be.

```
array(2) {
  [0] => int(4)
  [2] => string(1) "3"
}
```

Comment: i have edited my question please go through it if you can help me

Comment: Why don't u use an associative array?? It will make things less complicated
`array("read" => array("
    //Array of the read books
"), 
"unread" => array(
//Array of unread books
)
))`

Comment: actually working for some one else and i am bound to work with this as it is .